# How to Unit Test Function opening a json file?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

The function below opens and loads a Json file. My question is whats the best approach to test it?

```
def read_file_data(filename, path):
    os.chdir(path)
    with open(filename,  encoding="utf8") as data_file:
        json_data = json.load(data_file)
    return json_data
```

`filename` and `path` are passed in as sys.argv's.

I figured that i would need sample data in my test case for a start but not sure how i would actually use it to test the function

```
class TestMyFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_read_file_data(self):
        sample_json = {
                      'name' : 'John',
                      'shares' : 100,
                      'price' : 1230.23
                      }
```

Any pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: `self.assertEqual(sample_json, read_file_data(filename, path))`

Comment: First of all your code is only making calls to the API of the Standard Python Library. That code has already been tested and you shouldn't test it again, you should only test your own code. Second, the function involves the use of a resource (the file) which is external to your code: in unit tests, you normally mock those resources.
 This [article](https://www.toptal.com/python/an-introduction-to-mocking-in-python) might give you some ideas

Answer (score 4):

As stated above you do not need to retest the standard python library code works correctly, so by creating a hard coded file as also stated, you are defeating the point of a unit test by testing outside of your unit of code.

Instead a correct approach would be to mock the opening of the file using pythons mocking framework. And thus test that your function returns the json that's read in correctly.

e.g.

```
from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open
import json

class TestMyFunctions(unittest.TestCase):


@patch("builtins.open", new_callable=mock_open,
       read_data=json.dumps({'name' : 'John','shares' : 100,
                        'price' : 1230.23}))
def test_read_file_data(self):
    expected_output = {
                  'name' : 'John',
                  'shares' : 100,
                  'price' : 1230.23
                  }
    filename = 'example.json'
    actual_output = read_file_data(filename, 'example/path')

    # Assert filename is file that is opened
    mock_file.assert_called_with(filename)

    self.assertEqual(expected_output, actual_output)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you would want to do would be to make the JSON file, hardcode an in memory version of that JSON file and assert equals between the two.

Based on your code:

```
class TestMyFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_read_file_data(self):
        import json
        sample_json = {
                      'name' : 'John',
                      'shares' : 100,
                      'price' : 1230.23
                      }
        sample_json = json.dump(sample_json, ensure_ascii=False)
        path = /path/to/file
        filename = testcase.json
        self.assertEqual(read_file_data(filename, path), sample_json)
```

Comment: @ Jeremy Barnes, Thanks. Can you clarify what path and filename is pointing to? if its referring to an external json file then what is the point of sample_json?

Comment: Sample JSON is to be a hardcoded version of the data in the external json file. They are to be compared to ensure the proper operation of the read_file_data function.
That is what the `self.assertEqual` call is for.
In my experience, testing is generally making test cases where specific circumstances and specific input result in one and only one specific output or response from the program.
So, you write your JSON file, recreate it in the code and assert that the function returns a JSON that is EXACTLY what you intended.
Thank you for asking for additional clarity.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check these answers first:
   [How to use mock_open with json.load()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51138834/how-to-use-mock-open-with-json-load)
2. some of the answers are using `json.dump` instead of `json.dumps` interchagebly, which is wrong.
3. read, open, load, as stated are from Standard Python Library, already been tested, so you'd rather think about testing some actual column's values/types or some rows in your json file instead, and if you did that, this would not be a unit test anymore, it'll be an **integration test** since you have dependencies coupled to your method (json data in this case) which would be meaningless to purposely decouple them via mocking.